# Django сохранение изображения из формы

Tags: django

Подскажите как сохранить на сервер изображение, указанное в форме.

С формы информацию в бд сохраняю, считывая get или post запрос. Т.е. получается что я должен принять путь к изображению, но вот как его сохранить?

---

То есть чтобы загрузить изображение, можно при обработке страницы, куда приходят данные, делать так?

```
caption = request.POST['caption']
preDescription = request.POST['preDescription']
description = request.POST['description']
image = request.POST['image']
```

Потом уже использовать вот это?

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='news')
```

---

Сделал:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class News(models.Model):

    caption = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    preDescription = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='news')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from anime.models import *

class NewsForm(forms.Form):

class Meta:
     model = News
```

views.py

```
def addnews_status(request):

    a = NewsForm(request.POST)
    a.save()
```

Пишет вот что - 'NewsForm' object has no attribute 'save'.

Ошибку я перевести могу, но я не понимаю почему его нет? Делал всё как положено. Я хотя бы на верном пути?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> С формы информацию в бд сохраняю, считывая get или post запрос.

Неправильно делаете. Почитайте про [ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/), там все работает абсолютно автоматически.

Comment: дополнил..

Comment: Прочтите документацию, я дал ссылку

Comment: посмотрите ещё раз пожалуйста

Comment: На верном пути, только форма должна быть ModelForm, а не просто Form,  и она не сможет сохраняться, пока не проверите данные. Внимательнее читайте документацию, пожалуйста, там много полезного.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):  
    class Meta:
         model=MyModel

def handler_view(request):
     form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
     if form.is_valid(): form.save()
```

читаем документацию! хотябы наискосок